# Não foi possível carregar o tipo '<ProjectName>.MvcApplication' ao duplicar projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Dupliquei meu projeto no Visual Studio da seguinte maneira:

1° Entrei no sistema de arquivos e dei `CTRL C + V` na pasta `SiteTeste` que é a pasta do projeto.

2° Renomeei a pasta para `Siteteste2` e depois renomeei os arquivos `.csproj`,`.csproj.user` e `.user` ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3° Alterei o arquivo `Global.asax` ficando assim:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Siteteste2.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

3° Adicionei o projeto através do Visual Studio, e ele foi adicionado dentro do arquivo `.sln` ficando assim:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.27130.2027
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SiteTeste", "SiteTeste\SiteTeste.csproj", "{0DAAF99F-D5F0-47C7-B1CC-E042F0C5C3AC}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Siteteste2", "Siteteste2\Siteteste2.csproj", "{8F4DD610-3480-4B5D-AB6C-1538D4182C43}"
EndProject
Global
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {0DAAF99F-D5F0-47C7-B1CC-E042F0C5C3AC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {0DAAF99F-D5F0-47C7-B1CC-E042F0C5C3AC}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {0DAAF99F-D5F0-47C7-B1CC-E042F0C5C3AC}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {0DAAF99F-D5F0-47C7-B1CC-E042F0C5C3AC}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU        
        {8F4DD610-3480-4B5D-AB6C-1538D4182C43}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8F4DD610-3480-4B5D-AB6C-1538D4182C43}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8F4DD610-3480-4B5D-AB6C-1538D4182C43}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8F4DD610-3480-4B5D-AB6C-1538D4182C43}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {05F0005B-FC82-4B57-BAE6-9FA284547CA5}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
        HasPerformanceSessions = true
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Até ai ok, mas quando eu vou rodar qualquer um dos projetos eu recebo esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT:

Eu alterei o `namespace` do `global.asax.cs` e acaba causando esses erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando passo o mouse em cima do erro, ele pede para eu adicionar `using SiteTeste`

Comment: Entre no código do global.asax e veja o namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abra o arquivo Global.asax.cs e conserte o *namespace* para  ficar de acordo com o que consta no Global.asax

```
namespace Siteteste2
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.MvcApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {              
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        }
    }
}
```

Altere também o *namespace* das classes `WebApiConfig`,`FilterConfig` e `RouteConfig`.

Comment: LINQ, eu fiz isso,a principio achei que ia resolver, mas acabou causando alguns erros, da uma olhada no meu EDIT.

Comment: Só fazer os usings, cara

Comment: using do Siteteste (projeto origem)? pois é só essa opção que ele me da

Comment: LINQ faltou alterar o namespace das classes dentro do global, editei sua resposta e acrescentei essa informação ok ? Deu certo.